# Why do non-linear optical effects occur?

Tags: optics, non-linear-optics, optical-materials

Why do [non-linear optical effects](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nonlinear_optics) occur? Why do the materials respond differently at high intensities and at some resonant frequencies?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To paraphrase @Roger Vadim, the actual question is why do linear optical effects occur? In general they shouldn't. But if you limit yourself only to the linear term in Taylor expansion you will get linear optics.

To give more intuition think first of the limiting case when your medium is just vacuum. Then your light is governed my Maxwell's equations (we ignore all possible quantum effects) which are linear, hence linear optics.

What is linear? Linear means that the effect of the sum is the same as the sum of effects, i.e. every electric/magnetic field acts "on its own", unaware of the presence of other fields ("principle of superposition"): if you have fields $E_1$ and $E_2$, their combined effect will be the same as the sum of their individual responses.

In a non-vacuum medium, when your fields are not too intense, you can modify your Maxwell equations to to accomodate the material response (remember ${\bf D}$, ${\bf H}$, etc). Then you again have superposition principle and hence linear optics. Example: imagine you have two laser pointers, red and green. If you shine one of them on a piece of glass, the beam will refract by some angle (determined by material properties). If at the same time you turn on the other laser, the refraction angle of the first beam will not change, i.e. superposition holds, and everything is linear.

Now imagine that your second laser beam is very intense. When you turn it on, your piece of glass will become very hot due to absorbed energy (the closer the frequency of the second beam to one of the absorption lines of your glass, the more it will be absorbed and the more the heating effect will be). In general refractive index changes with temperature, so your first beam will now experience different refraction and its outgoing beam will go somewhere else. There you go, the response of the medium to the first laser beam depends on the power of the second one. The beams now "talk to each other" via piece of glass which is nothing but nonlinear effect.

Answer (score 1):

Because materials are generally non-linear, but their response can be linearized for small field values, which greatly simplifies calculations. See [linear response](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_response_function) and [Taylor expansion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor_series).